# Method for logging user access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Goal: Keep table of user logins and write a record on exit

Tried using API code to get Windows ID with idea of writing it after that.  Couldn't access the function.  Thought about using a username and password to read from a table and allow access if authenticated.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: The method you have suggested is the right way to go, create a table with user names and logins, then create a log entry every time they have been authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to log each open and close of the windows in the application.  http://allenbrowne.com/AppLogDocUse.html  I'm going to make the user logout through the login screen to track use.  Works ok for my purposes.